# Is there any better way to check popup window in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Now I'm using code like:

```
msg = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('div#msg').get_attribute ('style')
if 'display: none;' in msg:
     print("window doesn't popup")
    
if 'display:block;' in msg:
     print('windows popup')
```

However if I don't add `time.sleep(0.1)` above msg:

```
time.sleep(0.1)
msg = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('div#msg').get_attribute ('style')
```

Sometimes the result will not accurate.But I need very fast test,so I wonder is there any better way ,that I can check whether there is a pop window or any way I can wait less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just translated your selector to be xpath and combine with logic `@style!=""`, then using  [**`Explicit Waits`**](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to achieve it:

```
msg = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="msg" and @style!=""]'))).get_attribute('style')

if 'display: none;' in msg:
     print("window doesn't popup")
    
if 'display:block;' in msg:
     print('windows popup')
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```